# Xcode C++ "No matching member function for call ..."

Tags: objective-c, tesseract

I'm trying to use `tesseract` in my Mac application. Therefore I compiled `leptonica` and `tesseract`, copied all header-files and the .a-files to my project.

Afterwards I renamed the AppDelegate.m file to AppDelegate.mm.

Now I'm trying to use `tesseract` like this:

```
#include "baseapi.h"
...
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tess = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
tess->Init([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"tessdata"], "eng");
```

Unfortunately at the second line I'm getting the error:

```
"No matching member function for call to 'Init'"
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I make a mistake at compiling?

Here is my compiling bash-script: [bash-script link](http://pastebin.com/zspcsUzK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some Documentation for your api the best matching signature is

```
int Init (const char *datapath, const char *language)
```

In your case you are passing this

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"tessdata"]
```

which returns an NSString *, not a const char ptr

try this instead

```
tess->Init([[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"tessdata"] UTF8String], "eng");
```

Comment: I can't believe it!!! That's it!!! Xcode just gave me an absolute  unrewarding error. Thank you!